# Probability of presence of not defective products in a pack.

Tags: probability

In a pack of 50 products there mustn't be more than 2 defective products.
The probability of presence of 0, 1 or 2 defective products in the pack is the same.
Five randomly chosen products are not defective.
*What's the probability of the rest of the products in the pack being not defective too?*

**My attempt to solution:**
$$
   P_0 = P_1 = P_2 = \frac{1}{3} \\
   P_0 + P_1 + P_2 = 1
$$
Where $ P_i $ is the probability of presence of *i* defective products in the pack with 50 products.
I assumed that there *could* be present conservation law (hence the second equation).

The 5 selected products that are taken out of the pack form $ \frac{5}{50} = \frac{1}{10}\text{th} $ of the initial number of products in the pack.

If the 5 selected products are not defective, the $ P_{0} $ must have decreased in favour of $ P_1 \text{ and } P_2$ (the conservation law).

The question is: what's the new probability $ P'_{0} $ of no defective products being present in the pack?

Based on previous assumptions, I thought that $ P'_{0} = \frac{1}{3} - (\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{3} ) = \frac{3}{10} $.

Comment: Actually, if you get $5$ good items in your sample, the probability of $0$ defectives should increase rather than decrease.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's denote the events of $0$, $1$, or $2$ defectives by $D_0$, $D_1$, $D_2$; and the event of getting $5$ goods by $G$.

We are interested in the conditional probability $P(D_0 \mid G)$.

We have
$$P(D_0 \mid G)=\frac{P(D_0\cap G)}{P(G)}$$
Noting that $D_0\subseteq G$, we obtain
$$P(D_0 \mid G)=\frac{P(D_0)}{P(G)}$$
We know $P(D_0)=\frac13$.

We can also calculate 
$$ \begin{array}{lcl}P(G)&=&P(G\mid D_0)\cdot P(D_0)+P(G\mid D_1)\cdot   P(D_1)+P(G\mid D_2)\cdot P(D_2)\\
&=&1\cdot \frac13+\frac{9}{10}\cdot\frac13+\frac{48\choose 5}{50\choose 5}\cdot \frac13
\end{array}$$
You should be able to finish it from there.